# Unanswered question - editing doesn't move it to top

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

According to other posts here, editing my question should bump it to the top.  My question has been unanswered for several days now and I have edited it twice, this last time adding some more information I discovered about the problem.  Neither edit moved it up and it's not getting any attention at all.  What can I do?  I don't have enough points to put a bounty on it.

Comment: Which question are you talking about? Give link. And on which tab are you seeing?

Comment: are you talking about this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15215215/2147039) ? I can see that question in active question list.

Comment: Your right, it's there now.  It took quite awhile to become active.  I guess I wasn't patient enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit a question,it goes to top again that is true but then you have to choose **active** tab from the main page then only you can see it.

Here i can see your question in the active tab of [php](/questions/tagged/php)

[image]

Remember that after editing your question goes to top on active tab only.